# Unable to locate license assembly

Tags: visual-studio, infragistics

I am trying to use Infragistics NetAdvantage 2005 Vol 2 WinForms in Visual Studio 2005 running on Windows Vista. I am unable to drag an Infragistics control onto a windows form. I get the error:

> Failed to create component 'UltraTextEditor'.
>   System.ComponentModel.LicenseException:Unable to locate license
>   assembly.

I have tried to blank out my licenses.licx file but this does not fix the problem. I suspect the problem is that I run Visual Studio 2005 as Administrator and this account is unable to access the license.

Comment: Did you use the Infragistics installer to install the controls?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem with NetAdvantage 2006 for a legacy winform application.  Upon receiving a new pc, I refused to install NetAdvantage and just wanted the designer interface in VS to work. I was also receiving the "unable to locate license assembly" error even after installing Infragistics.License.dll and Infragistics.Office2007UI.Design.Support.v6.3.dll in the GAC.

The trick to this is two registry keys under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  One called **Infragistics** and another called **Infragistics.License**.  I won't reveal the contents of these keys to protect against dark figures in trench coats appearing, but you will find them on any pc with NetAdvantage 2006 installed.  I only found this after poking around on my old dev box.

DISCLAIMER:  I am a licensed developer for the component in question, and simply just didn't want to clutter my new pc with Infragistics software.  I also do not know if this will work for any subsequent versions of NetAdvantage but figured I'd at least share my experience.

Comment: I was given a VM with NetAdvantage 2006 installed but I wanted to get rid of it and the library installer was nowhere to be found. I followed the given steps to copy license information and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

NetAdvantage 2005 Volume 2 was CLR 1.x only and isn't expected to work in the Visual Studio 2005 designer.  You can see more details on that here:
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=8486

The specific exception that you are getting it is likely due to the Infragistics.License assembly not being present in your your GAC.  This assembly should be added to the GAC by the installer of the tool set.  Note that Windows Vista was released after NetAdvantage 2005 Volume 2 and the installer wasn't tested on Windows Vista.  Support for Vista was added with NetAdvantage 2006 Volume 3:
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=9983

If the Infragistics.License assembly isn't in the GAC, you could try running the installer again with administrator privileges.  You could also test with UAC disabled to see if that would help.  Another alternative would be to install a later volume of NetAdvantage as that would also put the Infragistics.License assembly in your GAC and the latest volumes will install without issue on Windows Vista.

Comment: I have disabled User Access Control and confirmed that the Infragistics.License is in my GAC. I still have this problem.

Comment: I have tested this and was able to drag an UltraTextEditor on a form in Visual Studio 2005.  You could test uninstalling NetAdvantage and manually removing the related registry entries and then reinstall NetAdvantage.  This worked for someone else who had licensing issues with TestAdvantage which uses the same license assembly.  You can see the thread here: http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/58218.aspx